# connect reactJS app with Angular application?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs

I am trying to integrate form.io code in my react project.
how can I add angular code in the ReactJS application and which dependencies should I install?

Comment: Why not use their react package?

Comment: You should try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formio

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about Micro Front-Ends. It requires a complicated answer. I advice you to start with this article https://medium.embengineering.com/micro-front-end-and-web-components-ce6ae87c3b7f or https://dev.to/dabit3/building-micro-frontends-with-react-vue-and-single-spa-52op Their you can find an examples with architecture